# install DOTNETNUKE form error

Tags: dotnetnuke

I'm trying to install Dontnetnuke but I've got problem at Install Page. It looks like i'm losing all css styles and images. I cannot even change language. Cannot proceed anything. Please help me this, Thanks in advance....

Here's the screen image:
[image: http://i725.photobucket.com/albums/ww253/KimGiunChua/loi_zpsc2554a7e.jpg]

Comment: Is "/dnn" an application declared under your website or just a folder? I think you need to verify if the DotNetNuke root correspond to an application root (website or web application in website).

Answer (score 0):

i have also faced similar issue i have resolved by replacing web.config with new web.config or you can replace whole dnn setup . i prefer Dnn Source package to install Dnn